# Rust add two numbers from stdin

Tags: rust

My goal is to first read an integer `n`, then `n` pairs of integers, outputting their sum.

A sample input would be:

```
3
1 2
2 2
1 3
```

And its respective output would be:

```
3
4
4
```

Here's what I have so far;

```rust
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut buff = String::new();

    let n: i32;
    stdin().read_line(&mut buff).unwrap();
    n = buff.trim().parse().unwrap();

    let mut sum;
    for _ in 0..n {
        stdin().read_line(&mut buff).unwrap();
        sum = buff
            .trim()
            .split_whitespace()
            .map(|x| x.parse::<i32>().unwrap())
            .sum::<i32>();
        println!("{}", sum);
    }
}
```

But it looks like the `sum` variable is carrying forward with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdin.read_line(&mut buff)` reads from stdin and *appends* it to `buff`, it does not clear the old contents. You need to call `buff.clear()` on every iteration:

```
for _ in 0..n {
    buff.clear(); // <- this
    stdin().read_line(&mut buff).unwrap();
    sum = buff
        .trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|x| x.parse::<i32>().unwrap())
        .sum::<i32>();
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```